# How to refer to only the first part of complex OpenStreetMap keys?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, hstore

I have a PostgreSQL table with OSM data. In the `hstore` type tags column I have the `key:value` components of the tags. In some cases there is two or more part of the key like `oneway:bicycle`, or `psv:lanes:forward`, and only after that comes the value.
How can I refer to only the first part of the key, so to all of the records that has keys that starts with `oneway`?
Because if I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM m_temp.osm_road WHERE exist(tags,'oneway')
```

it only returns where nothing is following the key, but the value.

Now I realize that I could search these records with regular expressions such as:

```
SELECT * FROM m_temp.osm_road WHERE tags::text ~'oneway:'
```

But that's just a workaround and I cannot fetch the values with `tags->'oneway:'`

Is there any solution to this what I missed?